# How to delete the row with swipe using AndroidSwipeLayout library on github

Tags: android, listview

I am making and app with a list view I want to swipe the row and there comes a button from the beneath the row. so for doing this I am using the code on [github]  [1](https://github.com/daimajia/AndroidSwipeLayout) .In it I have observed that the option for deletion appears on both swipe, I mean from left to right and from right to left. SO weather I swipe the row from the left to right or right to left it always show me delete option in the right corner. So I just want to disable the left to right swipe. How can i achieve that???

please suggest how can I do that  and please do not down rate my question  I want want to get the solution  and if you have an

Answer (score 1):

I'm sorry I don't have too much time to analyse it deeper, but since it looks like you really need a help, take a look at this [SwipeListView.java](https://github.com/47deg/android-swipelistview/blob/master/swipelistview/src/main/java/com/fortysevendeg/swipelistview/SwipeListView.java)

It's also at GitHub and has some lines that says:

```
/**
 * Enables both left and right swipe
 */
public final static int SWIPE_MODE_BOTH = 1;

/**
 * Enables right swipe
 */
public final static int SWIPE_MODE_RIGHT = 2;

/**
 * Enables left swipe
 */
public final static int SWIPE_MODE_LEFT = 3;
```

I hope this may help you :-)

Comment: I am using this same by 47 degree , I am successful in making right to left swipe and delete action on it , but the problem is left to right slide is not getting disable. If I did not assign anything to left to right slide it performs exactly the same functionality as I set for the right to left slide

Comment: and that is my main problem